# Understanding ansible tagging of roles in the playbook

Tags: ansible

Confused as to whether role tagging from the playbook is working properly, and, if so, the philosophy behind it.

Playbook

```
- hosts: Test-c7-1
  roles:
    - role: test.tag
      tags: tag2
```

Role/task

```
---
- debug:
    msg: "task - tag1 set"
  tags: tag1

- debug:
    msg: "task - tag2 set"
  tags: tag2

- debug:
    msg: "task - always set"
  tags: always

- debug:
    msg: "task - NO TAG"
```

When a matching tag is passed in, the role is run, and everything in the task list is executed regardless of tagging.

Matching tag:

```
ansible-playbook playbook/tagtester.yml --tags "tag2"

PLAY [Test-c7-1] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1]

TASK [test.tag : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1] => {
    "msg": "task - tag1 set"
}

TASK [test.tag : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1] => {
    "msg": "task - tag2 set"
}

TASK [test.tag : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1] => {
    "msg": "task - always set"
}

TASK [test.tag : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1] => {
    "msg": "task - NO TAG"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Test-c7-1                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

When an non-matching tag is passed, the role is STILL run, BUT the (non-matching) tag is passed down to the tasks, and only tasks with that tag (or tagged 'always') are executed.

Non-matching tag:

```
 ansible-playbook playbook/tagtester.yml --tags "tag1"

PLAY [Test-c7-1] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1]

TASK [test.tag : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1] => {
    "msg": "task - tag1 set"
}

TASK [test.tag : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [Test-c7-1] => {
    "msg": "task - always set"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Test-c7-1                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Is this expected behavior?
And, is there a way to tag a role (as well as a task - include_role) in a playbook to only filter whether that role *itself* is executed or not based on that tag passed in at execution?

Comment: You can easily validate the exact tags by the `--list-tasks` argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes, it is.

> And, is there a way to tag a role (as well as a task - include_role) in a playbook to only filter whether that role itself is executed or not based on that tag passed in at execution?

Since Ansible version 2.4 there are three ways of using roles:

- [roles declaration at play level](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles),
- [`import_role` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/import_role_module.html), and
- [`include_role` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html).

With `import_role` and `roles` declaration, Ansible concatenates the tags specified in the declaration and executes the tasks.

`include_role` works like a stand-alone task, i.e. it itself observes the tags.

---

<sup>**Notes**</sup>

<sup>- The same rule applies to `when` conditions.</sup>

<sup>- Before Ansible 2.4 `include_role` worked like `import_role` now.</sup>

<sup>- Reference [Differences Between Static and Dynamic](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#differences-between-static-and-dynamic)</sup>

Comment: OK thanks techraf.
So I guess there is some inherent danger in trying to filter out 'roles' based on tags, as you may pick up some unexpected task.
Regardless, looks like I'll need to find another approach to this, anyway.  I need my role in the playbook to loop through a var list.  Neither 'roles' nor 'import_roles' allow looping, and tagging 'include_roles' requires ALL underlying tasks be tagged as well.